# pyspark not saving when reading parquet files from directory

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to load a lot of parquet files from a directory to pyspark and then save them to another directory.

My code is as follows:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('input_folder') \
  .write \
  .parquet('output_folder')
```

I am getting a huge list of errors, starting from:

> Exception has occurred: Py4JJavaError An error occurred while calling
> o30.parquet.

When I try to work with one file - everything is fine:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('input_folder/file1.parquet') \
  .write \
  .parquet('output_folder')
```

Counting records working fine:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('input_folder') \
  .count()
```

What could be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that the first parquet file was empty. Hope it helps somebody.